# How to compute an optimally cost-effective cache strategy?

Tags: optimization, program-optimization

I am looking for advice in the following optimization problem. I have a website (system) that receives database updates. The updated information is later returned in queries made to the same system. In order to speed up the system the obvious solution is to cache data in each location. I have begun to decompose the times it takes to place data in different caches. I will end up with.

```
Cu = uth computation time
Su = storage required to store result of uth computation
SCn = storage cost using nth storage resource
Wn = storage cache write time for nth storage resource
Rn = storage cache read time for nth storage resource
```

I am ignoring local microprocessors caching for now. For example I want to make a storage purchasing decision. I can buy plenty of SSD, Spinning drives and/or RAM. But given the amount of possible caching I want to buy what makes most sense.

Here are some considerations for a cost function. Storage can be simplified since there will be an allocated space that will cost X dollars. I am struggling a bit more with timing. Clearly I could minimize only the time it takes to query and update. But that does not address responsiveness, we need servers to be responsive with every request. As opposed to the ability to process every single update and query at once in a couple of days, instead of three. I am constructing a $$ to seconds function. This function would imply, we are willing to pay $X for a computer that responds in Y seconds.

An optimization algorithm is needed, there are a lot out there and I am not sure which could be a good fit for this problem.

I am having a lot of difficulty finding research similar to this description. And I do know I will need to redo this optimization a number of times, so I will end up writing code so I don't have to do this every time.